# Android QR Code Scanning Using Zxing Library Turns Into Crash

Tags: android, zxing, qr-code, scanning

I have integrated zxing library to my app to scan QR code. As i press a button and starts the zxing scanning activity , the app crashes and give these following messages on logcat,

```
05-24 02:17:24.037: E/AndroidRuntime(516): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

05-24 02:17:24.037: E/AndroidRuntime(516): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
ComponentInfo{com.code.looknmove/com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/xml/preferences.xml from 
drawable resource ID #0x7f050000

05-24 02:17:24.037: E/AndroidRuntime(516):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)

05-24 02:17:24.037: E/AndroidRuntime(516):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)

05-24 02:17:24.037: E/AndroidRuntime(516):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)

05-24 02:17:24.037: E/AndroidRuntime(516):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)

05-24 02:17:24.037: E/AndroidRuntime(516):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

05-24 02:17:24.037: E/AndroidRuntime(516):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)

05-24 02:17:24.037: E/AndroidRuntime(516):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)

05-24 02:17:24.037: E/AndroidRuntime(516):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

05-24 02:17:24.037: E/AndroidRuntime(516):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)

05-24 02:17:24.037: E/AndroidRuntime(516):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)

05-24 02:17:24.037: E/AndroidRuntime(516):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)

05-24 02:17:24.037: E/AndroidRuntime(516):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

05-24 02:17:24.037: E/AndroidRuntime(516): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/xml/preferences.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f050000

05-24 02:17:24.037: E/AndroidRuntime(516):  at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResourceFd(Resources.java:860)

05-24 02:17:24.037: E/AndroidRuntime(516):  at com.google.zxing.client.android.BeepManager.buildMediaPlayer(BeepManager.java:97)

05-24 02:17:24.037: E/AndroidRuntime(516):  at com.google.zxing.client.android.BeepManager.updatePrefs(BeepManager.java:60)

05-24 02:17:24.037: E/AndroidRuntime(516):  at com.google.zxing.client.android.BeepManager.<init>(BeepManager.java:49)

05-24 02:17:24.037: E/AndroidRuntime(516):  at com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity.onCreate(CaptureActivity.java:165)

05-24 02:17:24.037: E/AndroidRuntime(516):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)

05-24 02:17:24.037: E/AndroidRuntime(516):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)

05-24 02:17:24.037: E/AndroidRuntime(516):  ... 11 more

05-24 02:17:24.037: E/AndroidRuntime(516): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: This file can not be opened as a file descriptor; it is probably compressed

05-24 02:17:24.037: E/AndroidRuntime(516):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAssetFdNative(Native Method)

05-24 02:17:24.037: E/AndroidRuntime(516):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAssetFd(AssetManager.java:426)

05-24 02:17:24.037: E/AndroidRuntime(516):  at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResourceFd(Resources.java:857)

05-24 02:17:24.037: E/AndroidRuntime(516):  ... 17 more
```

I am unable to detect whats the actual problem is. So some help is needed on the issue to resolve, to detect what is going wrong with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have copied and pasted all of our `android/` code into your project, and don't really understand what you've copied. Copying our app this way is *strongly* discouraged. If you're new to Android, it is probably too complex to try to reuse our code anyway.

1. Remove all code you copied from `android/` and `core/`
2. Add `android-integration/`
3. Implemented barcode scanning with 3 lines of code as per http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent

Comment: I just followed an tutorial on how to integrate zxing in android app. Neways , i will give it a try , hope this will solve my problem. Thanks. Btw , i have added the android project as library to my app & added the core.jar as library to my app. Should i remove all of these?

Comment: You don't need to add anything but `android-integration` to use Intents. The link above is all you need.

Comment: Using this it is asking that barcode scanner has to be installed like that.but my requirement is that qrcode scanning has to be done without installing that.it has to be done by using my application.is that possible?please give any suggestions to this.

Comment: Yes but you need to write your own app and not copy ours. Use bits if you need. If you aren't able to do this I don't think you have a choice but to use Intents right? BS is to going to work better than your copy anyway

Comment: Can i save decoding image in sdcard using BS ?

Answer (score 1):

Same problem, fixed by this link:

[michalu zxing barcode](http://michalu.eu/wordpress/scanning-and-generating-barcodes-using-zxing-library-on-android/)

As library, use his zxing library that you can download from link at bottom of the page. It works for me

Answer (score 0):

I  have faced the same issue when i used the Zxing library and i solved it by this technique

Give Complete Path of your Launcher Activity in Manifest file like "PacakageName.StartActivity"